# @EnableZuulProxy cause junit tests fail to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-feign

The main application relies on microservices which mainly work through feign clients except for one - uploading of files.  Since feign clients only works with text-based data, RestTemplate along with zuul proxy is used instead.

Instead of having a separate Zuul Proxy server, the main application is doubled as Zuul proxy server so the the url to the service is by reference of the main application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class MainApplication {
   ...
}
```

The problem is this.  Without @EnableZuulProxy, all the JUnit tests runs fine.  With @EnableZuulProxy, all the tests that loads the application contexts failed.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zuulEndpoint' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration$RoutesEndpointConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'zuulEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'server'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
      at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
      at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
      ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'server'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
      ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
      ... 65 more
```

I have read this -> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1094 but it doesn't work for me.

Further information:

Found that the tests that failed are repository tests which are annotated with @DataJpaTest and controller tests that are annotated with @WebMvcTest.  So, the tests that failed are the ones that attempt to load the whole application contexts.  Is there any way to ignore @EnableZuulProxy when running unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

I still could not avoid the application context error during JUnit test if there is @EnableZuulProxy.

Initially, find work around by simply @EnableZuulProxy in profiles which are not used in tests.

Finally, found better way to use RestTemplate in Spring Cloud by simply annotating it with @LoadBalanced.  It serves the same intended purpose, which is to use a logical service id rather than a full actual url.  @LoadBalanced allows the RestTemplate to make use of the Eureka registry to access the microservices using their logical ids.